# How to add a 'Host-only Adapter' to a VirtualBox machine via Vagrant file configuration?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

A lot of answers out there are only applicable version 1 of Vagrant file configuration. e.g.

```
config.vm.network :hostonly, :adapter => 2
```

The new `public network` does not support this feature. e.g. this line here

```
config.vm.network "public_network", bridge: 'vboxnet0'
```

Will throw an error because `vboxnet0` is not a network interface like `en0`. Here is a screen shot:

[image]

I have also tried

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
  vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--hostonlyadapter2", "vboxnet0"]
```

But it has no effect on the virtual machine.

How can I create a new interface like this?

[image]

I am using

- Mac OS X 10.10.1
- VirtualBox 4.3.20
- Vagrant 1.6.5

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think I have found an answer.

```
config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
    config.vm.network "private_network", :type => 'dhcp', :name => 'vboxnet0', :adapter => 2
end
```

This will create a host-only adapter as I wanted in my question

Comment: Further to this, if you happen to have a custom DHCP server already configured, you need to make sure the `dhcp_ip`, `dhcp_lower` and `dhcp_upper` match your custom DHCP server otherwise vagrant will throw an error.

Answer (score 2):

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.box = "ubuntu/xenial64"
  config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
end
```

Works for me, though I already had 'vboxnet0' configured by default, it created a new host-only network 'vboxnet1'.

I was not able to use vboxnet0 further it throws conflicting network error. Creating multiple vms with above config worked for me using vboxnet1 by default.